# Taylor series and mean value theorem question: $f'(a)< f(a+1) -f(a) < f'(a+1)$ with $f''(x)>0$

Tags: calculus

Taylor series how to evaluate?

Comment: Is that $f''(x)=0$ for every $x$? Or for one specific $x$?  What do we know about $f''$ at other points?

Comment: Hi sorry it is supposed to be $f’’(x)$>0 for every x. I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

With the mean-value-theorem, we have

$$\frac{f(a+1)-f(a)}{(a+1)-a}= f(a+1)-f(a) = f'(c)\tag{1}$$

where $a<c<a+1$. Apply the Taylor's expansion to $f'(a+1)$ and $f'(a)$ around $c$,

$$f'(a+1)=f'(c)+f''(c)(a+1-c)>f'(c)$$
$$f'(a)=f'(c)+f''(c)(a-c)<f'(c)$$

where $f''(c) > 0$ is used. Thus,

$$f'(a)<  f'(c)  < f'(a+1)$$

Hence, with (1),

$$f'(a)<  f(a+1) -f(a)  < f'(a+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $g'>0$ then $g$ is strictly increasing. So if $g=f'$ and $g'=(f')'=f''>0$ then $g=f'$ is strictly increasing.

So if $c\in (a,a+1)$ then $f'(a)<f'(c)<f'(a+1).$

And by the Mean Value Theorem there exists some $c\in (a,a+1)$ such that $f(a+1)-f(a)=\frac {f(a+1)-f(a)}{(a+1)-a}=f'(c).$